# Java Search a .txt file for a given number with different format (100,50 or 100.50)

Tags: java, file, search, wildcard

I want to search a given txt file for a number and return the line where it was found. This number can have different formats. It can be written with a , or . or something completely different. I know that the input number always looks like this: 100.50; 3424.00; 0.12 ...

My current code detects these numbers only if they are in a line without other characters.
The code divides the number into two parts (100.50 -> front: 100 and back: 50). Then I add the wildcard "." and use the method matches(front + "." + back)

How I can find the number if it is in a line that isn't just the number?

Thank you for your help!

```
private static int searchTotal(String pictureID, String value) throws IOException {

    int counter = 0;
    String front = value.substring(0, value.length() - 3);   //dividing the value into 100,50 -> 100 and 50
    String back = value.substring(value.length() - 2);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(pathTXTFiles + "/" + pictureID +".txt")); //input txt
    String s;

    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        counter++;
        if (s.matches(front + "." + back)) { //searching with the wildcard
            return counter;         //counter gives me the line of the searched number
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How I can find the number if it is in a line that isn't just the number

Comment: You'll have to allow other characters before and after: ``s.matches(".*"+front + "[.,]" + back+".*");``

Comment: @f1sh I know it is very simple and short but I really think that your comment should be an answer. Otherwise this question is still unanswered and it really isn't.

Comment: Would suggest you to use Pattern.compile(regex) though for performance reasons than matches. Also, do some unit tests for all the cases - for example what happens if your number repeats or just the front and back repeats etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to allow other characters before and after:

```
s.matches(".*"+front + "[.,]" + back+".*");
```

otherwise `matches` will only return true if the line consists only of one decimal number.